# Cannot turn off Vim text highlighting

Tags: vim, highlighting

So for some reason, after copying and pasting text from Sublimetext into VIM, VIM is now auto-highlighting text as I type:

[image: VIM highlighted text]

This highlighting persists even when I change the colorscheme (this is with :colorscheme blue)

[image: VI highlighted text with new colorscheme]

The only things I can find online about this regard syntax highlighting and search highlighting, not text highlighting - how do I turn this off? I just want my text to output as normal without it being highlighted some weird color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running the command `:noh`.

Comment: you can also try :nohl